# ElasticSearch - Bucket average with Nested fields aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I am trying to execute the following query in the elasticsearch. The scenario is I have one field in the document which has 3 subfields: time1, time2, and id, the field is an array of objects having the above fields.

I want to calculate the average of difference b/w time2 and time1 for all the items.

Query being executed is :

```
`{
   "query":{"match_all":{}},
   "aggs":{
      "total_time_diff":{
          "nested":{"path":"diff_list"},
          "aggs":{
              "diff_r":{
                 "sum":"doc['time2'].date.getMills()-doc['time1'].date.getMills()"
              }
          }
      },
      // Here I need average of the sum which is calculated in total_time_diff "sum" aggregation
      "avg_diff":{
        "avg_bucket":{"buckets_path":"total_time_diff"}
      }
   }
 }`
```

I am gettting following error:

```
{
   "error": {
     "root_cause": [],
     "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
     "reason": "",
     "phase": "fetch",
     "grouped": true,
     "failed_shards": [],
     "caused_by": {
       "type": "class_cast_exception",
       "reason": "org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.nested.InternalNested cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.InternalMultiBucketAggregation"
     }
   },
   "status": 503
}
```

Index Mapping

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "response_index": {
        "date_detection": false,
          "diff_list": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "age": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "time2": {
                "type": "date"
              },
              "time1": {
                "type": "date"
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you add your schema mappings for the index?

Comment: can you also add which version of elasticsearch are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
"aggs":{
              "diff_r":{
                 "sum":"doc['time2'].date.getMills()-doc['time1'].date.getMills()"
              }
          }
```

isnot a bucket selector and so the total_time_diff wont work inside the last aggregation (avg_diff).

use a script instead (like)

```
"script": "doc['time2'].date.getMills()-doc['time1'].date.getMills()"
```

Let us know it it word.

Answer (score 0):

I have found different solution for your problem here. Instead of doing the sum in the script and then looking for bucket script aggregation to work on it. i used [average script aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html) using script.

Avg bucket aggregation will not work here for this sibling aggregation as the aggregation doing sum is not [multi bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-avg-bucket-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-pipeline-avg-bucket-aggregation).

i have made some changes to the script to compute the difference between two date fields. Following query should work for you.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "total_time_diff": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "diff_list"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "diff_r": {
                    "avg": {
                        "script": {
                            "source": "doc['diff_list.time2'].value.millis - doc['diff_list.time1'].value.millis"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you.